# org.mockito cannot be resolved to a module

Tags: mockito, java-11

I am getting this error in eclipse:

```
"org.mockito cannot be resolved to a module" in module-info.java
```

I have tried with an upgraded version of mockito-core.jar 3.0.0 but problem not resolved. Eclipse version is : 2018-12 (4.10.0)

```
module somemodule {
    exports abc.changer;

    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires org.mockito;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: do you have that dependencies added in gradle?

Comment: i have maven project

Comment: where is your module-info.java located (which src directory?) and what is the scope of your mockito dependency?

Comment: module-info.java located in src/main/java and then scope of mockito dependency is test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can resolve it with separate modules eg module-info.java and module-info.test. it require maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.x. for complete solution plese go to https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-11-testing-in-the-modular-world.html